# with or without a save button for saving textarea content

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a lot of textareas on a page and want to save the contents automatically by typing inside

```
$('textarea').on('input', function(){
    let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let story = $(this).val();
    $.post('a_pro.php', {fn: 'tx_change', args: [id, story]}, function(data){
        console.log('saved');
    });
});
```

On server side I have a `php` function `tx_change` to store data in a `mysql` table.

Everything works fine, regardless what is the speed of typing, regardles I'm on a wire on wireless connection...

I even tried typing inside one textarea and at the same time pasting a content inside another one - it works - everything is saved.

Question is - why people use a SAVE button at all?
I suppose there is a hidden risk of using this?

In a second I type 4-5 characters, so each second the `javascript`, `php` and `sql` code is executed five times, and plus time for establishing connection and plus time for callback function (write console)...

I simply cannot believe that there is no any problem with this.

Any advice?

Comment: so your abacus is having trouble keeping up?

Comment: for example, automatically saving may trigger 20 HTTP requests in one minutes for one user, manually hit 'Save' button may only have one or two requests in one minutes. it will cause big difference on server loading. so for automatically saving, you may have to consider how to cache, merge multiple requests etc.

Comment: @Sphinx, I think there is much more http requests on auto saving because there is more then 100 key typing in a minute, and each of them run the `input` event

Comment: yes, so for auto saving, you have to think about how to merge the requests in backend or front end to decrease HTTP requests or DB requests.

Comment: @Sphinx, is there any standard way to do this merging?

Comment: People use save buttons for very different reasons. They could use simple HTML forms instead of spending development time on AJAX calls, they might want to submit the content as a whole instead of smaller pieces, it might confuse users if they don't find a way to save their data. That is completely separate of the amount of HTTP requests. You could easily use a debounce function or save the data in a time interval to resolve those issues. It's not clear to me what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Ivar, I'm looking for one of two answers - 1-freely continue your job without a save button - 2-you must have a save buton because...

Comment: no standard methods. you have to find some solution based on actual situation you face. typically, if the content is very critical and can't bare any loss, uses 'Save' button may be better. so if the users forget to save,  hah, you can say it is user's fault, not yours. but you can save the content in a time interval in local storage, then restore the content if necessary.

Comment: There is not one clear cut answer to that. Both could work fine. It's a matter of opinion and UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that true you will increase overhead on server using auto save method.

if you still want auto save, you should decrease number of request and you can do it by using debounce function.

```js
const debounce = (func, delay) => { 
    let debounceTimer 
    return function() { 
        const context = this
        const args = arguments 
            clearTimeout(debounceTimer) 
                debounceTimer 
            = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay) 
    } 
} 

var textareaElem = document.getElementById("textarea"); 
textareaElem.addEventListener('keyup', debounce(function() { 
        alert("Hello\nNo matter how many times you" + 
            "click the debounce button, I get " + 
            "executed once every 300 ms!!") 
                        }, 300)); // <-- you can change debounce time
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks... just a question - what if a user type a letter and close the tab after 290 ms?

Comment: @qadenza that way a very small amount of data will lose instead of the whole content.